# NPM installing global packages in /root/node_modules

Tags: centos, node.js

I've installed and used node/npm on more systems than I care to count, the majority being Linux/CentOS machines. I have a CentOS 7 installation that installs global packages in `/root/node_modules`. Thus, they won't be globally available. `npm root` also confirms this. Of course, I could probably use prefix, or any similar NVM-ish hack; but I'd rather not.

I also tried installing as `devDependencies`. One side effect was that pm2 cluster module was not spawning processes on all my cores, as I've seen on my other CentOS development server.

Please help me out. I've repeatedly uninstalled, purged and reinstalled node, npm and yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158453/10902281) to an identical question on StackOverflow,

> In case you want to have local packages at a globally available path, you could install to your filesystem root. cd / and from there npm install .. all users would have read access to that folder by default. Node will find those packages.

I hope this helps someone else!